# How to select tab buttons in java tab panel with QTP/UFT?

Tags: automated-testing, java, qtp, hp-uft, vbscript

I want to switch between tabs in Java application using QTP 11.0. The problem is that tab buttons are not seen by qtp object spy as separate objects, the whole tab pane is seen as JTabbedPane:

[image]

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Now trying to perform click operation on JTabbedPane using x, y coordinates:

```
JavaWindow("java window name").JavaTab("JTabbedPane name").Click 220, 10,"LEFT"
```

But don't know how to debug cause I can't see the actual place where the click is performed in application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was trivial, tab is selected by its name with a function `Select`:

```
JavaWindow("java window name").JavaTab("JTabbedPane name").Select "Tab Name"
```