# How to select an item in java menu with automation tool QTP/UFT?

Tags: automated-testing, java, qtp, hp-uft, menu

The task is to open (click) menu item, e.g. `File >> Open` using QTP 11.0

[image]

You can check here [how to spy drop-down menu properties with object spy](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17635/how-to-spy-drop-down-menu-in-qtp-uft).

Below is the code that is autogenerated by QTP when I drag-and-drop `JavaMenu "File"` from object repository:

```
JavaWindow("File: Test.java").JavaMenu("File").Select
```

I expected (from my experience of [working with Java Tabbed Pane](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/14741/how-to-select-tab-buttons-in-java-tab-panel-in-qtp)) that the next code should work:

```
JavaWindow("File: Test.java").JavaMenu("File").Select "Open"
```

But encountered `Run Error: Inappropriate quantity of arguments or assigning value of property: JavaWindow("...").JavaMenu("...").Select` (my translation of localized QTP message)

So it lools like `Select` should not take any arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to access menu items on drop-down pane with `descriptive programming` and use `Select` function without arguments:

```
JavaWindow("File: Test.java").JavaMenu("File").JavaMenu("label:=Open").Select
```

This works fine, but finally I came to the usage of pure descriptive programming (DP) to avoid usage of object repository:

```
JavaWindow("label:=File: Test.java*").JavaMenu("label:=File").JavaMenu("label:=Open").Select
```