# How to spy drop-down menu in QTP/UFT?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft

I want to spy objects of drop-down menu as I need to get [it's descriptors for descriptive programming](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15809/how-to-open-an-item-in-java-menu-using-qtp). As soon as I click the Spy button, the drop-down menu is hidden.

How to spy drop-down menu in QTP/UFT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl` key is used to temporary disable spying, so one could perform preparatory operations.

So you sould do the next steps:

1. Click the Object Spy button [image: Object Spy button]
2. Hold `Ctrl` key
3. Expand the menu
4. Release the `Ctrl` key
5. Spy menu

Then you can check here [how to code select action for drop-down menu in UFT](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15809/how-to-open-an-item-in-java-menu-using-qtp-uft).

Comment: that's pretty quick answer: `asked asked Mar 17 '16 at 8:39` and `answered Mar 17 '16 at 8:39` -- good job :)